# Laravel4 storing a collection

Tags: backbone.js, laravel-4, async.js

The question I have is about how to store a collection of models to a RESTful back end.
I'm using Backbone.js, and I'm considering to either:

1. Use Async.js parallel method and post / put each model separately in a loop, after which a general callback method is triggered;
2. Send a collection of objects to the back end, and use a database transaction to make sure that all models are properly saved with a single commit;

The first method seems to cause a lot of overhead, because I have to make different calls to save the models.

But when considering the second approach, Laravel4 does not by default allows to perform a post / put on a collection.

What would be your preferred approach, and more importantly, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach is definitely the way to go in my opinion, it reduces the latency and saves bandwidth if you use it with a large number of models since all the HTTP stuff (headers, etc) will be sent only once.

In your controller, use something like this (it may not work, I don't have access to any Laravel installation to test it) :

```
public function postCollection() {
    $collection = Input::get("collection");

    DB::transaction(function() {
        foreach ($collection as $data) {
            // In this example we assume it's a collection of users
            // Of course in a real app you would also do input validation
            $user = User::create(["name" => $data->name, "email" => $data->email]);
        }
    })

    // Example success response, will be automatically serialized to JSON
    return ["status" => "success"];
}
```

This loops over the `collection` element of your JSON input, which should be a list of models. Then it should obviously do validation and possibly other stuff. The whole loop is wrapped into a `DB::transaction()`, which will rollback everything if an exception occurs inside of it.

Comment: I had the same idea in mind. I'm not sure if the architectural style concept of REST is respected with this approach though. I accept this answer anyway, thanks for you help!

Comment: @KimGysen by using a PUT request I think it's REST-compliant.